# if/else jQuery using custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-data

I am trying to do an if/else in jquery using an custom attribute. i named the attribute "data-id" because i was hoping i can use the .data() thing of jquery but somehow it did not work.

Here is what i tried last:

```
 if($("#marke").val() == '0'){
    $("#modellselect").attr("data-id").not('0').hide();
 } else{
    $("#modellselect").attr("data-id").show();
 }
```

So, if the marke-value is 0 i  want to show only the moddellselect with data-id 0, and if the marke-value is not 0, i want to show all of the modellselect's.

Comment: Where are you executing that bit?

Comment: It also seems like you have multiple elements with same id `modellselect`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.filter` for this instead

```
if($("#marke").val() == '0'){
    $("#modellselect").filter(function(){
        return $(this).data('id') != '0'
    }).hide()
 } else{
    $("#modellselect[data-id]").show();
 }
```

(Remember, Id's should be unique - looks like yours are not)

Comment: Should be able to use `$("#modellselect[data-id!='0']")` or  `$(".modellselect[data-id!='0']")` selector ?